# Can we assign a Typescript class to a useState field of a Functional Component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I was going through [this blog - useEffect complete guide topic](http://overreacted.io) and thought to use a - simple Typescript class and update states and see how useEffect behaves.

Is it ok to assign Typescript class to a useState variable ??

You can find the link to the example here in [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-useeffect-typescript-dfdns?file=/src/components/typescript/TypeScriptComponent.tsx)

If JSX...For that matter, what if its just a ES6 class and not Typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the instance of a class in state but you never update it.

You must note that even though you add items to the stateHelper class but the instance is not changing and hence the useEffect will not be executed again.

However in order to store instances that remain constant throughout the scope of your component instance its better to make use of `useRef` instead of `useState`

```
const TypeScriptComponent: FunctionComponent = (props): JSX.Element => {
  // Creating an instance from a (Typescript) Class and assigning it to useState
  const stateHelper = useRef<StateHelper>(new StateHelper());
  const [list, setList] = useState<string[]>([]);

  // ........on button click
  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    stateHelper.current.addList("Shwetha");
    // Calling an async data from the Typescript class this time
    const result = await stateHelper.current.fireData();
    if (result) {
      stateHelper.current.addList(result);
      const newList = stateHelper.current.getList();
      console.log("New list is: ", newList);
      setList(newList);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    stateHelper.current.addList("Pramod");
    const newList = stateHelper.current.getList();
    setList(newList);
    console.log("component did mount");
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        {list.length > 0 &&
          list.map((item: any, index: number) => <p key={index}>{item}</p>)}
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Add Me</button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default TypeScriptComponent;
```

Comment: Could could use useState definitely, but since you do not need a update functionality it more understandable if you use useRef

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man. That makes sense....!

The reason I was thinking to `useState` is because if we could have something like this

```js
const [customObj, setCustomObj] = useState({}); // primitive object
```

....why not have a fully fledged instances of a class

```js
const customObj = useState(new CustomClass())[0]; // fully fledged instances of a class
```

*Does that makes sense ?*